# perl - compare two column of two SQL query from 2 databases

Tags: sql, perl, mariadb

in perl, i want to insert year and parti from database 2 to database 1 if name from database 1 and name from database 2 is equal

```
database 1                               database 2
-----------------------------------      ----------------------------------
table truc                               table truc2
-----------------------------------      ----------------------------------
id   name      year  parti               id   name       year   parti
-----------------------------------      ----------------------------------
  1  Lapin                               14   Lapin      2014   MODEM
118  Koala                               33   Murène     1347   EELV
 14  Murène                               2   Ragondin   4218   SP
  3  Ragondin                             3   Koala      1512   CPNT
```

i want the result:

```
database 1                               
-----------------------------------      
table truc                               
-----------------------------------      
id   name     year  parti        
-----------------------------------     
  1  Lapin    2014   MODEM                  
118  Koala    1512   CPNT                     
 14  Murène   1347   EELV                       
  3  Ragondin 4218   SP
```

thanks for any response,

my code of perl and sql are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58858146/perl-compare-two-column-of-two-sql-query)

Answer (score 3):

Read from one database and update in the second one:

```
my $query2 = $db2->prepare('SELECT id, name, sex, year, parti FROM truc2');
my $query1 = $db1->prepare('UPDATE truc'
                           . ' SET year = ?, parti = ? WHERE name = ?');

$query2->execute;

while (my @row = $query2->fetchrow_array) {
    $query1->execute($row[3], $row[4], $row[1]);
}
```

Tested with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;
use feature qw{ say };

use open IO => ':encoding(UTF-8)', ':std';

use DBI;

my $db1 = DBI->connect('dbi:SQLite:dbname=:memory:', "", "",
                       { sqlite_unicode => 1 });
$db1->do('CREATE TABLE truc'
         . ' (id INT, name TEXT, sex VARCHAR, year INT, parti TEXT)');
my $db2 = DBI->connect('dbi:SQLite:dbname=:memory:', "", "",
                       { sqlite_unicode => 1 });
$db2->do('CREATE TABLE truc2'
         . ' (id INT, name TEXT, sex VARCHAR, year INT, parti TEXT)');

my $insert1 = $db1->prepare('INSERT INTO truc (id, name, sex)'
                            . ' VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
$insert1->execute(@$_) for [  1, 'Lapin',    'M'],
                           [118, 'Koala',    'F'],
                           [ 14, 'Murène',   'A'],
                           [  3, 'Ragondin', 'F'];

my $insert2 = $db2->prepare('INSERT INTO truc2 (id, name, sex, year, parti)'
                            . ' VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$insert2->execute(@$_) for [14, 'Lapin',    'A', 2014, 'MODEM'],
                           [33, 'Murène',   'F', 1347, 'EELV'],
                           [ 2, 'Ragondin', 'M', 4218, 'SP'],
                           [ 3, 'Koala',    'F', 1512, 'CPNT'];

my $query2 = $db2->prepare('SELECT id, name, sex, year, parti FROM truc2');
my $query1 = $db1->prepare('UPDATE truc'
                           . ' SET year = ?, parti = ? WHERE name = ?');

$query2->execute;

while (my @row = $query2->fetchrow_array) {
    $query1->execute($row[3], $row[4], $row[1]);
}

my $verify = $db1->prepare('SELECT * from truc');
$verify->execute;
while (my @row = $verify->fetchrow_array) {
    say "@row";
}
```

Comment: the problem with your script is i have thousand name, i can't put thousand name in "$insert1->execute(@$_) for [  1, 'Lapin',    'M'],"

Comment: @sdgrhjgh: That's just to emulate your situation in my database. What *you* need is just the 7 lines of code in the first snippet.

Comment: i don't understand this line, my $query1 = $db1->prepare('UPDATE truc'
                           . ' SET year = ?, parti = ? WHERE name = ?'); what i put in "?"

Comment: Those are just placeholders, they get replaced 5 lines later in the loop when the sql is executed: https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE database1.truc
    JOIN database2.truc2  ON database1.truc.name = database2.truc2.name
    SET database1.truc.year = database2.truc2.year
        database1.truc.parti = database2.truc2.parti;
```

No binding, no copying data into arrays, no loss of `id`, etc.

Comment: i try to do that in perl : UPDATE worldmap.worldmap_table t1
SET t1.severity = 1000
WHERE t1.host IN
(SELECT h.name
FROM host_inventory as i, hosts as h WHERE i.hostid=h.hostid  and h.available=1)

Comment: @sdgrhjgh - That looks like SQL, not Perl.