# perl - insert value if column word is missing

Tags: mysql, sql

in perl, i want to insert missing line if

```
database 1                               database 2
-----------------------------------      ----------------------------------
table truc                               table truc2
-----------------------------------      ----------------------------------
   parti                                 id   parti missing_line
-----------------------------------     ----------------------------------
   MODEM                                14   MODEM   0
   EELV                                 33   EELV    0
   SP                                    2   SP      0
   CPNT                                  3   CPNT    0
```

after 5 min i have this, SP and MODEM in pati column is missing, i want to insert 1 if any word in column is missing:

```
database 1                               database 2
-----------------------------------      ----------------------------------
table truc                               table truc2
-----------------------------------      ----------------------------------
   parti                                id   parti missing_line
-----------------------------------     ----------------------------------
                                        14   MODEM   1
   EELV                                 33   EELV    0
                                         2   SP      1
   CPNT                                  3   CPNT    0
```

thanks for any response,

my code of perl and sql are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58858146/perl-compare-two-column-of-two-sql-query)

Comment: How is this related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58873020/perl-compare-two-column-of-two-sql-query-from-2-databases ?

Comment: this is not same question, i want update or insert 1 if word is missing in column

Comment: Removed the Perl tag. There's no need for Perl here.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this looks like it should work (but I don't have time to test it):

```
UPDATE database2.truc2 t2
SET t2.missing_line = 1
WHERE t2.parti NOT IN
(SELECT t1.parti FROM database1.truc t1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use MySQL `update ... join ... set ... where ...` syntax. Using a `left join` and `where ... is null`, you can identify the unmatched records:

```
update database2.truc2 t2
left join database1.truc1 t2 on t2.parti = t1.parti
set t2.missing_line = 1
where t1.parti is null
```

Another option is to use `not exists`:

```
update database2.truc2 t2
set t2.missing_line = 1
where not exists (
    select 1 from database1.truc1 t2 where t2.parti = t1.parti
)
```

I would advocate against using `not in`, which produces unexpected results when dealing with `null` values; if any of the values returned by the subquery is `null`, then the `not in` condition actually becomes a pass-through (equivalent to `1 = 1`), which would result in all the records in the source table being updated.